# Should this sentence use the word "one" or "you"?

Tags: pronouns, syntactic-analysis

Is the sentence

> One only has to look at the size of Claire’s house to know that you can make a lot of money as a doctor.

correct?

I'm not sure whether mixing the words "one" and "you" in the same sentence is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1):

It's a stylistic pecadillo at best. One shouldn't mix points of view in the same piece of writing.

It's syntactically awkward to use **one** and **you** interchangeably, since it may cause the reader momentary confusion and create an undesireable ambiguity.

As a matter of formality, old-school stylists like Warriner say that using "you" in a general sense - in places where one can't *see* a "you" - is a bad thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's acceptable. *One* and *you* are not referring to the same hypothetical person, so they don't need to agree with each other. *One* refers to the person who is coming to the conclusion based on looking at the house, while *you* refers to doctors.

As Rob Ster points out, mixing points of view in a single sentence is awkward, so it might be better rephrased as

> One only has to look at the size of Claire's house to know that doctors make a lot of money.

On the other hand, the simple statement "doctors make a lot of money" is somewhat sterile, the original wording has more stylish nuance.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Barmar. It is correct to say :

One only has to look at the size of Claire’s house to know that you can make a lot of money as a doctor.

As one means anyone , but you refers to doctors.

But the best to say :

One only has to look at the size of Claire's house to know that doctors make a lot of money.

Or 
You only have to look at the size of Claire's house to know that doctors make a lot of money.